# Socket.IO in unity5 ,C# - how to emit string or object?

Tags: c#, websocket, socket.io, unity-game-engine

I'm new to C# and unity. I'm trying to send a simple string to the server using Socket.IO:

`socket.Emit("collision", "Surface")`
It doesn't work, i get:

[image: how to send/emit string trough socket io in unity?]

I tried a bunch of things, the following code works only with strings as numbers:

```
var dataToSend = new JSONObject();
dataToSend["colider"] = new JSONObject("2"); // this works..
socket.Emit("collision", dataToSend);
```

the following gives `null` - third one in the image below..

```
var dataToSend = new JSONObject();
dataToSend["colider"] = new JSONObject("Surface");
socket.Emit("collision", dataToSend);
```

Thig gives empty object `{ }`

```
var dataToSend = new JSONObject();
dataToSend["colider"] = new JSONObject(JsonUtility.ToJson("Surface"));
socket.Emit("collision", dataToSend);
```

I get:

[image: works for number as string but not for string as string.png]

**So how can i send/emit this "Surface" string to the server?** Why is it so hard, it's just a simple string .. ?! thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it: `socket.Emit("collision", JSONObject.CreateStringObject("Surface"));`

There are a bunch of more specialized functions - the API can be found inside `SocketIO/JSONObject/JSONObject.cs` - for the [**Socket.IO** library downloaded from assets store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21721)